# construct a Python regular expression where there is a sharing of prefix

Tags: python, regex

I want to achieve the following:

say I have two regex, `regex1` and `regex2`. I want to construct a new regex that is of `'prefix_regex1 | prefix_regex2'`, what syntax should I use to share the prefix, I tried `'prefix_(regex1|regex2)'` but it's not working, since I think it's confused on the bracket used as group rather than making the `|` precedence higher.

example:

I have two string that both should match the pattern:
`prefix_123`
`prefix_abc`

I wrote this pattern: `prefix_(\d*|\D*)` that tries to capture both cases, but when I run it against `prefix_abc` it's only matching `prefix_`, not the entire string.

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: The engine is not "confused". `re.findall` just outputs captured substrings only if capturing groups are defined in the pattern. Use non-capturing groups. `'prefix_(?:regex1|regex2)'`

Comment: I just added an example

Answer (score 0):

This site might help with this problem (and others).  It lets you tinker with the regex and see the result both graphically and in code:  https://www.debuggex.com/

For example, I changed your regex to this: prefix_(\d+|\D+) which requires 1 or more digit or non-digit after "prefix_" Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but it's easy to experiment with the site I shared above.
Hope it helps.